# How to convert utf-8 fancy quotes to neutral quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing a little Python script that parses word docs and writes to a csv file. However, some of the docs have some utf-8 characters that my script can't process correctly.

Fancy quotes show up quite often (u'\u201c'). Is there a quick and easy (and smart) way of replacing those with the neutral ascii-supported quotes, so I can just write `line.encode('ascii')` to the csv file?

I have tried to find the left quote and replace it:

```
val = line.find(u'\u201c')
if val >= 0: line[val] = '"'
```

But to no avail:

`TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment`

Is what I've described a good strategy? Or should I just set up the csv to support utf-8 (though I'm not sure if the application that will be reading the CSV wants utf-8)?

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [`Unidecode` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to automatically convert all Unicode characters to their nearest pure ASCII equivalent.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
line = unidecode(line)
```

This will handle both directions of double quotes as well as single quotes, em dashes, and other things that you probably haven't discovered yet.

Edit: a comment points out if your language isn't English, you may find ASCII to be too restrictive.  Here's an adaptation of the above code that uses a whitelist to indicate characters that shouldn't be converted.

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> whitelist = set('µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ')
>>> line = '\u201cRésumé\u201d'
>>> print(line)
“Résumé”
>>> line = ''.join(c if c in whitelist else unidecode(c) for c in line)
>>> print(line)
"Résumé"
```

Comment: Wonder why not ...  â€œconsolidated appropriations act, 2021â€.
section 6402 of public law 107â€“171.
 105â€“83:
 for â€œrural and expensesâ€.
striking â€œ2010 through 2021â€
 for â€œfarm  and expensesâ€
departmentâ€™s

Comment: @gseattle was there a point to your comment?  Looks filled with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) to me.

Comment: works great in english... other languages... not so good.

Comment: @rubmz very good point.  See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign to a string, as they are immutable, and can't be changed.

You can, however, just use the regex library, which might be the most flexible way to do this:

```
import re
newline = re.sub(u'\u201c','"',line)
```

Comment: You might want to catch both left and right double quotes with `u'[\u201c\u201d]'`.