# How to remove double quotes(") in csv file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, opencsv

My input in csv file is like below:

```
  ￼ “No”    “ename” age  “gender”   “salary”
    1   “aaa”   23     f          1000
    2   “bbb”   24     m          2000
    3   “ccc”   25    “f”         3000
    4   “ddd”   35     m          4000￼
    5   “eee”   27     f          5000￼
```

> Below code is written to remove quotes given in .csv file.

```
import csv

csv.register_dialect('myDialect', delimiter=',', doublequote=False,
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, skipinitialspace='True')

f = open("pythonFiles/normal.csv", 'r')

normal = csv.reader(f, dialect='myDialect')

for data in normal:
    print(data, len(data))
```

The output is shown below. I want to remove all of the quotes.

```
['“No”', '“ename”', 'age', '“gender”', '“salary”'] 
['1', '“aaa”', '23', 'f', '1000'] 
['2', '“bbb”', '24', 'm', '2000'] 
['3', '“ccc”', '25', '“f”', '3000'] 
['4', '“ddd”', '35', 'm', '4000'] 
['5', '“eee”', '27', 'f', '5000']
```

Comment: You're not writing to a file in your code? Have you redirected `print` to a file?

Comment: Maybe `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` is not the right option.

Comment: It appears your dialect uses *whitespace delimiter* and the quotes aren't NONE but fancy quotes.

Comment: The problem may be because your csv does not seem to be using actual quotes, but rather some unicode alternative.

Comment: @Jaxi Which are, well, *actual* quotes, just… fancy ones. :)

Comment: @deceze yeah, that's what I meant :p

Comment: This also may be of use?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977618/how-to-convert-utf-8-fancy-quotes-to-neutral-quotes

Comment: Running code in ubuntu and saving file normally only ? Did you mean quotes i have to save in some other way

Comment: I think we're starting off on the wrong foot here. That csv file is not a file containing comma separated values.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting I agree. I'm surprised the output is as stated if `delimiter=','` is set. I'd expect there to be only one column since spaces are actually used as delimiters in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could just use `replace(...)`?

```
for data in normal:
    data = [d.replace('“', '').replace('”', '') for d in data]
    print(data, len(data))
```

You can also do `lstrip(...)` and `rstrip(...)` if you want to keep internal quotes intact:

```
for data in normal:
    data = [d.lstrip('“').rstrip('”') for d in data]
    print(data, len(data))
```

Please note that the quotes you are using are "left double quote" (`“`) and "right double quote" (`”`) not just simple "double quote" (`"`).

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from André's answer above, I have modified your code below

```
import csv

    csv.register_dialect('myDialect', delimiter=' ', doublequote=True,
                         quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, skipinitialspace='True')

    f = open("normal.csv", 'r')
    f = f.read().replace('“', '').replace('”', '').splitlines()
    normal = csv.reader(f, dialect='myDialect')

    for data in normal:
        print(data, len(data))
```

If you are happy with it, please select André's answer as the accepted one.
cheers.