# Bootstrap Modal not appearing - jinja2

Tags: jinja2, bootstrap-modal

I'm the thousandth person to ask a similar question, so I'm certain it's something simple.

First time working with boostrap / jinja in Chrome. Simply put, the button is there, but clicking it does nothing. The data is all populating from Jinja just fine, and the jinja is rendering out the for loops properly, with matching id's between target calls and div id's.

**EDIT: After following the suggestion of looking at this URL: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#usage and cutting and pasting the sample "live demo" that isn't working either. Could be something environmental I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            {% for loc, content in variant.location.items() %}
            {% set modal_id = day.header + item_name +variant.variant_name %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{modal_id}}">{{ loc }} : {{ content.quantity }}</button>
            {% endfor %}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>

  {%block modals%}
    {% for loc, content in variant.location.items() %}
      {% set modal_id = day.header + item_name + variant.variant_name %}

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="{{ modal_id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 10000000">                
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div classs="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>STUFF</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    {% endfor %}
  {%endblock%}
</html>
```

Comment: This could be related to the `id` attributes. They must be unique on the page. In particular, Bootstrap depends on this. Your `modal_id` doesn't appear to be unique - `day.header + item_name + variant.variant_name`. I can't see what these variables are, but based on your `for` loop you probably want the `id` to depend on `loc` and/or `content` (which it currently doesn't).

Comment: it actually is unique right now, but you're right in future there may be overlap in the future.

But as I mentioned, even a raw test 'id = test' on both sides, without any generated id, doesn't work. There seems to be something more fundamental I'm missing.

Comment: Does your HTML template derive from a `base.html`? I can't see bootstrap CSS and JS in the above template. Is it being loaded anywhere?

Comment: @costaparas no it doesn't. It's jinja rendering an index.html, via Flask. No JS. Like I say, this is my first time using this setup extensively, and I feel like there's something I haven't found in the support docs.The JS is directly in the head. This is what's actually being generated: https://imposing-fin-299523.wl.r.appspot.com/

Comment: What I meant was that your HTML doesn't appear to load the Bootstrap JS and CSS at all, so I assumed maybe you were loading it in a `base.html` Jinja HTML template, which is standard practise in Flask.. In any case, I've added an answer below that explains the two issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your generated HTML, I can see two main issues.

Your `id` attributes contain non-standard characters, which often cause problems for libraries like Bootstrap. Please familiarize yourself with the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may
> cause compatibility problems

Remove the non-standard characters (such as `(`, `)`, `/`, `,` and what appear to be non-ASCII smart quotes (`“` and `”`)) from your `id` attributes, which should solve this problem.

The other issue is that your generated HTML doesn't seem to have the Bootstrap CSS or JS loaded anywhere at all. Without the JS, the modals wouldn't do anything. The JS is what makes the modals appear.

You need to load these at the start, along with jQuery which is a dependancy for Bootstrap.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing loading those, and added them. Progress!

I didn't realize how much was unescaped. So I went down the rabbit hole with this, and it seemed like using [unidecode] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977618/how-to-convert-utf-8-fancy-quotes-to-neutral-quotes) to escape the smart quotes and creating a custom filter based on this made sense.